# Why does setting a domain on a cookie prevent me from expiring it on-demand?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I expire a cookie by setting the expiration in the past, like this:

```
 myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
```

This works great...until I set the Domain.  I set the domain, like this:

```
myCookie.Domain = ".mydomain.com";
```

(Note the leading dot there, to encompass this domain and subdomains -- not sure if that's relevant.)

I am trying to delete this cookie from a subdomain -- "apps.mydomain.com".  (This is the domain from which the cookie was set...)

When I do this, it will no longer expire on-demand by setting the expiration date in the past.  I run the same code that worked prior to setting the domain, but then check the cookies, and it's still there.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The Firefox Firebug Firecookie https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firecookie/ plugin might help you debug this. Also read up on the rules for settings paths in different domain situations. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try just mydomain.com without the leading "." - any difference?